# How to execute Console.log and setTimeout sequentially in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, settimeout

```
(function() {
    console.log(1); 
    setTimeout(function(){console.log(2)}, 1000); 
    setTimeout(function(){console.log(3)}, 0); 
    console.log(4);
})();
```

Hello All,

When I run the above code, it produces the following output: 1,4,2,3

So, instead of producing 1,4,2,3 I want the output to be 1,2,3,4 but by using setTimeout() method only.

Can anyone please help me out on how to produce 1,2,3,4 by having setTimeout() method and making modifications to it.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify things.. wrap the `setTimeout` with a `Promise` - that will give you the ability to also use `async` and `await` keywords and simplify your logic

```js
 (async function() {
        function sleep(interval) {
          return new Promise(resolve => {
             setTimeout(resolve, interval)
          })
        }
        console.log(1)
        await sleep(1000)
        console.log(2)
        await sleep(1000)
        console.log(3)
        await sleep(1000)
        console.log(4)
    })();
```

Comment: how do I only modify setTimeout??, In your above code it seems like you have added sleep after every console, but the question is only setTimeout should be modified..